# remove parent node from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like the following

```
 <div id="basedata-legend-land" class="legends">
   <p class="update_villages_2013">Villages</p>
   <p><img src="url" alt="legend" class="update_villages_2013"></p>
   <p class="district_boundaries">District Boundaries</p>
   <p><img src="url" alt="legend" class="district_boundaries"></p>
</div>
```

As you can see, i have used the same class name for `p` element and the `img` inside the other `p` element. I want to remove these elements when clicking on a button based on the class name. For that i did something like this

```
$(`.legends .update_villages_2013`).remove();
```

This works but when the `img` is removed, it leaves a empty `p` element. I want to remove that as well. So basically if i run this code

```
$(`.legends .update_villages_2013`).remove();
```

this is how the div should appear

```
<div id="basedata-legend-land" class="legends">
       <p class="district_boundaries">District Boundaries</p>
       <p><img src="url" alt="legend" class="district_boundaries"></p>
</div>
```

I couldn't just use the `parentNode` property because if i do, it will remove the main div as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:has()` to select elements that have a matching descendant.

```
$(`.legends *:has(.update_villages_2013)`).remove();
$(`.legends .update_villages_2013`).remove();
```